# How to change the value of an element inside an object in an array

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I'm pretty much new to the VF scene. I have a requirement where I need to update the value of a field in an object which is in an array. I am currently using JS to invoke an action function. Here is my reference:

This is the component calling the JS function

```
 <apex:outputPanel styleClass="menu-cell active" rendered="{!IF(showDescription = 'true',true,false)}" onclick="(function(){
   changeDescription('{!formId}','false');
 })()" >
   <span>Description</span>
   <c:activeStatus />
 </apex:outputPanel>
```

This is the JS function

```
function changeDescription(formId,response) {
        console.log(formId,response);
        const boolValue = response;
        changeDescriptionValue(boolValue);
    }
```

And, this is the action function:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="changeDescriptionValue" reRender="formPrev,formInputRenderer">
                <apex:param name="boolValue"  value=""  assignTo="{!formFields[0].Show_Description__c}" />
            </apex:actionFunction>
```

I would like to pass the the value 'boolValue' to the respective array Element (replacing the [0]).

How do I do this?

Thanks,
AADHIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just getting into UI development in Salesforce, then it's recommended to learn and use Lightning Web Components instead.

That said, if you're working with legacy (existing) code, then the established pattern here is to ensure that you have a checkbox/boolean field available in each object in your controller/extension. The way that Visualforce works makes it so that Javascript has a hard time interacting with the controller/extension state directly (and an even harder time with collections inside of a controller/extension).

In other words, you really don't want to be using Javascript to do this. Visualforce is the View (the 'V' in 'MVC'), so it should be focused on presenting data. Keep the logic in the controller and/or extension (the 'C' in 'MVC') if you can.

If you're working with a list of SObjects (Account, Opportunity, My_Custom_Object__c, etc...) and it already has a checkbox field that you can use, then `<apex:inputField value="{!myRec.My_Checkbox_Field__c}" />` is the way to go.

It's a similar story if you have a list of a custom Apex class that you're iterating over. Make sure there's a Boolean member variable you can use, and use `<apex:inputCheckbox>` instead of `<apex:inputField>`.

If you don't have a checkbox field or boolean member variable that you can use, then you should create a wrapper class in your controller/extension to add a boolean variable.

E.g.

```java
// Adhering to some basic style guidelines here:
// - class names start with a capital letter and UseTitleCase
// - variable names start with a lower-case letter
// - collections use a plural name (accounts, myRecords, etc...)
public class MyControllerExtension{
    private ApexPages.StandardController stdCon;
    public List<SelectionWrapper> selectRecords;

    public MyControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController con){
        stdCon = con;
        selectRecords = new List<SelectionWrapper>();

        // You need to put some data into selectRecords here if you want to display
        //   something on your page.
        // In most cases, you'll execute some query and loop over the results
        for(My_SObject__c loopRecord :[SELECT Id, Name, ..., Some_Field__c FROM My_SObject__c WHERE <some filter here>]){
            SelectionWrapper wrappedRecord = new SelectionWrapper();
            wrappedRecord.isSelected = false;
            wrappedRecord.record = loopRecord;
            wrappedRecord.someData = loopRecord.Name;

            selectRecords.add(wrappedRecords);
        }
    }

    public class SelectionWrapper{
        // You need to have a getter and setter to be able to use data on a Visualforce page
        // You could create "get<variable name>()" and "set<variable name>()" methods
        //   but using {get; set;} takes care of that for you automatically
        // Less typing is generally better
        public Boolean isSelected {get; set;}
        public My_SObject__c record {get; set;}
        public String someData {get; set;}
    }
}
```

```html
<apex:page standardController="My_SObject__c" extension="MyControllerExtension">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selectRecords}" var="wrapper">
            <!-- 
                By using a wrapper class, each row has its own dedicated variable for
                  us to use as a checkbox.
                Salesforce's processing is able to keep items in a single list correlated
                  to one another, so there's no need for explicit javascript.
            -->
            <apex:column>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrapper.isSelected}" />
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column>
                <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.record.Name}" />
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column>
                <apex:outputText value="{!wrapper.someData}" />
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

That example isn't complete, it's just meant to give you an idea of how to proceed.

The important idea here is that you should make sure that you have all the fields/variables that you need inside of each instance of an object in a list. If you don't have everything you need, you make a wrapper so that you *can* have everything that you need.

Comment: Well said Derek, I got the idea of the standard approach, thank you !